# How would you say "origin of the moon"

Tags: translation

In the same way that "Nihon" (日本) means "origin of the sun" how would you say "origin of the moon" in the same way?

Comment: Are you basically just asking what is the kanji for moon so you can swap it out for 日?

Comment: 「月本」なんて言葉があるなら、読み方は「げっぽん」かな……

Comment: No I mean if "Nihon" means "Sun's origin" I want to know what the equivalent of that is for "moon" or "night". I only need to know how the word would be spelled in English.

Comment: 日本 means Japan. Its etymology is based on putting together the kanji for "sun" and "origin," in reference to it being in the east. But there is no word that consists of the kanji for "moon" and "origin." If you wanted to talk about the actual origin of the moon, you would phrase it completely differently.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase this: I'm writing a Japanese-inspired fantasy novel, and I want the name of the fictional kingdom to reflect the real world japan. I'm trying to come up with a name for the kingdom that would evoke "night" or the "moon". Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Aeon mentioned what such a coined word, with moon instead of sun, would be potentially pronounced as above. Geppon. But there's no factual answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I have all I need

Comment: Or Tsukimoto, which sounds more "Japanese"? You can name it anything you want...

Comment: One of my coworkers family name is [月本]{つきもと}。。。

Answer (score 3):

「月{つき}の起源{きげん}」 would be just about the only term used in the real Japanese-speaking world that means "the origin of the moon".

If you  used 「月（の）本」, regardless of how it is read, you would need to explain what you intended to mean by that.  It sounds highly fictional/creative (or plain nonsensical) without an explanation.